# Behavior of trigonometric function in different quadrants

Tags: trigonometry

In the 1st quadrant tan function increases from 0 to ∞.That's justifiable to me since sine goes from 0 to 1 while cosine goes from 1 to 0 in the first quadrant.

However,I couldn't understand why tan increases from -∞ to 0 in the 2nd quadrant.

Shouldn't it be decreasing from  ∞ to 0 since both sine as well as cosine decrease in the 2nd quadrant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second quadrant, $\cos \theta < 0$ and $\sin \theta > 0$, so $\tan \theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} < 0$.

Have a look at the graph below. It shows $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ in red, and $\tan\theta$ in black. The dotted vertical line indicates $\theta=\pi/2$. Bear in mind that, by definition, $\tan \theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$, so we can calculate $\tan\theta$ by dividing the heights (i.e., the $y$-coordinates) of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$.

When $\theta$ approaches $\pi/2$ from the left, we have $\tan\theta \approx \infty$. I've drawn some red circles to highlight the values of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$, and an arrow pointing toward $\tan\theta$. But when $\theta$ is on the other side of $\pi/2$, we have $\tan\theta \approx -\infty$ (drawn in blue). This is because, while the value of $\sin\theta$ has remained stable around $1$, the sign of $\cos\theta$ has flipped from $+$ to $-$.

Very informally, we have $\frac1{+0}=\infty$ and $\frac1{-0}=-\infty$.

[image]

Comment: And at just a little over $\pi/2$, $\cos \theta$ is a tiny negative number, and $\sin \theta $ is nearly $1$, so $\tan \theta$ is a very large negative number. By $\theta  = 3\pi/4$, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are equal in magnitude, but opposite in sign, so $\tan \theta = -1$; as you approach $\theta = \pi$, $\sin \theta$ is positive but nearly $0$, while $\cos \theta$ is almost $-1$, so $\tan \theta$ is a small negative number.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,but why does it increase from -∞ to 0?Is there some differentiation technique for increasing and decreasing functions involved here?

Comment: Thank you John Hughes.So do you mean that at little over π/2 tan  θ  is so large that it can be considered as -∞ and the same for when it is very small that it can be considered as 0.

Comment: @PragatiJoshi I added some more comments and a diagram. Does that help?